# Conditional redirect by htaccess

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

From last 3 hours i'm trying to get a proper solution but failed. So, i think that is the time to post it here.

I have a two WordPress website.

Old Site has 4 page.
I want to redirect every request of old website redirect to new domain except that homepage, 3 other page & everything on wp-admin.

So, output will be-

```
http://www.sitea.com - no redirect
http://www.sitea.com/?page_id=1 - no redirect
http://www.sitea.com/?page_id=2 - no redirect
http://www.sitea.com/?page_id=3 - no redirect
Everything on wp-admin - no redirect

Everything else - redirect to http://www.siteb.com
```

Thanks in advnace

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as your very first rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# ignore these URLs
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=[123]$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# redirect rest to siteb.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?siteb\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.siteb.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. That return a page not found error instead of redirecting when i tried with wrong page id. BTW my site is a wordpress site.

Comment: Try my updated rules. Make sure they are placed before other rules.

Comment: What was the URL you entered originally? Also try my updated rule

Comment: `sitea.com/?page_id=1` won't be affected as per your requirement.